# systemd-journald delete logs after a specific date

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

Months ago, my computer had a hardware issue, and I reset the BIOS settings and RTC clock by pulling out the CMOS battery. Later when I put it back and restarted the computer, it worked correctly, but the RTC time was set to 2120-08-27. However, systemd-journald started recording logs on this day, which caused lots of troubles (e.g. currently, whenever I view the latest logs, journald always show me logs on that day), so I want to delete them. After doing some research, all I could find is how to delete old logs, rather than new ones. I want to keep my old logs and only delete these incorrectly dated logs. Are there any ways to do that? Thank you.

Distribution: Arch Linux
systemd version: 249.5